# Is there a way to selectively import data into Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-insert

I'm new to SQL and trying to figure out an issue caused by a data cap issue. For a school project I need to load a few large tsv files but one is so large that it maxes out the space I have (10.7 million rows). Luckily, the other table in the relation is much smaller (1.1 million rows). I'm looking to do something like this,

```
while(large_table != EOF) {
     Check if any of the primary keys from the small table are a sub-string in the foreign keys string in the large table.

     If one of the primary keys from the small table is a sub-string in the foreign keys string in the large table, insert that row.

     Else, skip that row
}
```

Is this possible? Is there a `INSERT CHECK` option for doing this that I could put into a loop? Is there something in Oracle SQL Developer that can handle this? The issue I'm stuck with is that I can't import both datasets before writing a query to handle this. My google searches haven't yielded anything even remotely useful. Perhaps I'm not using the correct keywords? Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: If you really wanted to, I suppose you could use SQL Loader with a preprocessor script where you implemented the logic you outlined in whatever client-side language you preferred.  I would tend to wager, though, that you'd be better served opening up Excel or your spreadsheet of choice, importing the data there, and doing your pre-processing in Excel since I'm assuming this is a one-time operation not something you are trying to productionalize.

Comment: Setup the tsv as an external table and then only insert the rows you want

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into those options. Something I just thought of was possibly breaking them up into smaller chucks, (e.g. large_table_1, large_table_2, etc.). Maybe that would work? Thank you for providing some  options to look into!

Comment: You can import all your data into table and delete unwanted rows with the same SQL (or enforcing constraints), no need to introduce new possibilities for errors (debug your code). You can use partitioning to break your data into chunks without different tables.

Comment: @astentx I think I know what you're talking about. I'll try that. Thanks. I'm working ahead so I have time to tinker.